# Downloading files from the server in a Django application

Tags: python, django

I want an app in my Django project to generate a list of files stored at a known location on the server, present them as a list to the user, with links for them to download.

I am comfortable with Python, and am also familiar with Jinja templating syntax, rendering a template etc.. The bit I am struggling with is the concept of MEDIA files in Django. Everything seems concerned with handling uploaded files. I simply want to access files at a known location on the server (one which is however, outside of my Django project).

- Is this possible?
- Is this workflow sensible or am I fundamentally misunderstanding a core concept?
- Is there some kind of approach (like `collectstatic`) that should be used, to pull all media files into the project for deployment and then allow them to be served?

I am just getting in to Django and have made some basic sites and applications which work well. The fundamentals seem to make sense to me. This is my first attempt a doing some file downloading, and this is where I have run into issues.

Note: I have a feeling that perhaps getting files from outside the Django project might be quite iffy in terms of security. Perhaps it is, but for this application, it will be hosted entirely internally on our work intranet. So if there is a way to manage this, even a slightly hacky-one I would be interested.

Comment: If these files already exist at a known location on the server, in what way aren't they static files?

Comment: I did think this initially. However, if I put that known path into STATICFILE_DIRS, and then run `collectstatic` they are not collected. All of the examples that I looked at always has CSS or JavaScript files as their static assets. These are *.zip files - does that make a difference?

Comment: But why do you need to collect them? If they're already in a known location why can't you point your webserver straight at them?

Comment: I was under the impression that static files should be "collected" and then referred to from within the project using `{% load static %}{{ static path/to/file }}`. Is it valid to just have the path directly to the file, if it is known? My application will only be small, so this would be manageable I think.